# How to use external libraries in Visual studio?

Tags: c#, windows, xaml

I wanted to try to use external libraries, and use them within Visual Studio. How could I do? I downloaded from the website of the libraries NAudio, to break an MP3 file, and contains files .dll..come use classes within the project c #?

Comment: Are the managed or unmanaged?  There are very different ways to use the two different types.  Is there any documentation on the site as to how to use them?

Comment: Install Nuget and see if the libraries you need are handled by it.

Comment: Add them as a reference, simple as that. If they are native you need to use PInvoke. Can you specify your problem at all?

Comment: the documentation is this: http://naudio.codeplex.com/documentation.I don't know the difference between  managed or unmanaged.I installed the extension Nuget for Visual Studio, but how do I use it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right click on references and select "Add Reference"

Then in the dialogue select 'browse' and find the .dll you need on your file system:

[image: screenshot]

[UPDATE] As others have said in comments its generally easier to resolve dependancies and update external libs if you can use NuGet for your external libraries rather than downloading the .dll directly - a brief intro to using NuGet from Visual Studio can be found here:

http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/managing-nuget-packages-using-the-dialog

Answer (score 2):

right click on your project in the solution explorer -> **add reference** -> choose your dll files; after that try **usin** on the top of your class code, but the **dll**s should have been wrote with one of .NET languages

Comment: I have to put them in any particular folder before?

Comment: no the visual studio automatically will copy it in the build folder

Comment: Not me makes them look inside the folder but it gives me a chance to put the mark only to some default extensions